# Place image at location with Planetary.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg

I'm using the plugin @ planetaryjs.com (& d3) to render a globe to screen.
The tutorials show how to add "pings" at a specific location using canvas commands which is great...

But I'd like to add an image to a specific lat/lng, and it to display with 3d transforms so it looks like it's spinning with the planet...

Unfortunately I'm at a loss -- I've tried importing SVG and png images but can only get them to display in '2d', and don't rotate with the planet.

Can anyone suggest any plugins or starting points to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking all over the web for something just like this, Nothing existed, so I made a plugin that will work directly with planetary.js

It is still being updated on github but the basic gist is this.
Use the main planet.projection() to convert lat,lng into projected coordinates.

Here is the basic usage.

```
var coords = planet.projection([(object.lng), object.lat])  
var img = new Image()
img.src = "/char.png";

var geoangle = d3.geo.distance([object.lng, object.lat],[-
planet.projection.rotate()[0], -planet.projection.rotate()[1]]);

//geo angle = radians (around 90 degrees)
if (geoangle > 1.57079632679490)
{
    //Behind Sphere > 90 degrees
} else {
   context.drawImage(img, coords[0] ,coords[1], 50 ,50)
}
```

Above is a snippet from the plugin I made, I essentially copied the "ping" plugin that already exists and changed the code to create objects/images instead.

Link to github repo: https://github.com/Sheaffy/planetary.js-add-objects-plugin